Interplay of fontspec and subfiles poisons luaLaTeX font cache
I'm using luaLaTeX to compile a document using subfiles and a TrueType font I'm shipping in the repository with the document itself, similar to this question. Somehow, this reproducibly poisons the luaotfload cache, forcing me to run luaotfload-tool --cache=erase to compile the document again. Is this a bug, or am I holding it wrong?
I've built a minimal working example. It's available on GitHub, I'll show the main parts here:

There's a simple main document that loads a subfile (which is notably stored in a subfolder):
\documentclass{article}

\input{header/header}

\begin{document}
    Hello World!

    \subfile{subfiles/chapter01}
\end{document}


The subfile is simple:
\documentclass[../main]{subfiles}

\begin{document}

This is chapter 1.

\end{document}


The header loads a custom font from the header directory:
\usepackage{subfiles}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[
Path = \subfix{./header/},
UprightFont = certainly-not-IBMPlexSans.ttf,
]{example-font}



On my system, provided we start with an empty font cache (i.e. after running luaotfload-tool --cache=erase), I can compile any document fine, e.g. the main document (log shortened):
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.18.0 (TeX Live 2024) 
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2024-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-11-02>
[…]
No file main.aux.
(./subfiles/chapter01.tex)
[1{c:/texlive/2024/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./main.aux))

 406 words of node memory still in use:
   3 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 3 kern, 1 glyph, 4 attribute, 48 glue_spec
, 4 attribute_list, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 1:1,2:28,3:6,4:1,5:27,6:4,7:100,9:22,11:2
<./header/certainly-not-IBMPlexSans.ttf>
Output written on main.pdf (1 page, 8308 bytes).
Transcript written on main.log.

That's a happy luaLaTeX – and the log shows the font was loaded from the expected path. Let's cd into the subfiles directory and build the chapter:
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.18.0 (TeX Live 2024) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./chapter01.tex
LaTeX2e <2024-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-11-02>
[…]
No file chapter01.aux.

[1{c:/texlive/2024/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./chapter01.aux))
 406 words of node memory still in use:
   3 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 3 kern, 1 glyph, 4 attribute, 48 glue_spec
, 4 attribute_list, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:22,3:4,4:1,5:25,6:2,7:66,9:18,11:2
! error:  (file ) (type 2): cannot find file ''
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

Oops! It's trying to find an empty-named file just when we expect it to load the font.
Running luaotfload-tool --cache=erase fixes this, we can now build the chapter:
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.18.0 (TeX Live 2024) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./chapter01.tex
LaTeX2e <2024-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-11-02>
[…]
(./chapter01.aux)
[1{c:/texlive/2024/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./chapter01.aux))
 406 words of node memory still in use:
   3 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 3 kern, 1 glyph, 4 attribute, 48 glue_spec
, 4 attribute_list, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:22,3:4,4:1,5:25,6:2,7:66,9:18,11:2
<.././header/certainly-not-IBMPlexSans.ttf>
Output written on chapter01.pdf (1 page, 7714 bytes).
Transcript written on chapter01.log.

But if we now cd back out and try to compile the main document, it fails:
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.18.0 (TeX Live 2024) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2024-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-11-02>
[…]
(./main.aux)
(./subfiles/chapter01.tex)
[1{c:/texlive/2024/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./main.aux))

 406 words of node memory still in use:
   3 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 3 kern, 1 glyph, 4 attribute, 48 glue_spec
, 4 attribute_list, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 1:1,2:28,3:6,4:1,5:27,6:4,7:100,9:22,11:2
! error:  (file ) (type 2): cannot find file ''
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

This can be repeated ad infinitum.
If the font file name isn't certainly-not-IBMPlexSans, but something available system-wide, this will actually work, but compiling one of the document will read the system file instead of the local one.
Am I holding this wrong? Is there a better way of loading a local font?

have you tried using \ifSubfilesClassLoaded in the header file rather than \subfix?

I had thought about trying to load different font files depending on what file is the main file, but couldn't find a combination that worked. I haven't used \ifSubfilesClassLoaded specifically, though, how would you use it?

I would just put the \setmainfont into the conditional i.e. \ifSubfilesClassLoaded ... insert \setmainfont for the subfile(s) and then, in the else part, do the same for the class. I don't know this will work. but \subfix looks dubious in \setmainfont to me. so I would try to see what happens if you specify the font without inserting macros into the specification.

Thanks! That didn't work (same behaviour as before). What does work is having a second copy of the font file with a different name and using one version for the subfile, one for the main file. So it seems like some information is cached, keyed under the font file name, and the system somehow can't cope with the path changing if the file name stays the same.

that path looks wrong if you're using \subfix. but I don't know on windows ....
